# Can I write an decoded images as a feature to Tensorflow tfrecord and then read it?

Tags: tensorflow, jpeg, decode, tfrecord

I am building the TFRecords version of the ImageNet data, using the code in [build_imagenet_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py)

Each image is saved as a string in a tf.train.Example protocol buffer

`example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/height': _int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': _int64_feature(width),
      ...
      'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(image_buffer)}))`

When reading the TFRecords files, it is need to call tf.parse_single_example op and tf.image.decode_jpeg op.

I want to know can I store the decoded images as a feature into tf.train.Example features?

If it is OK, it will not call tf.image.decode_jpeg op when reading the TFRecords files. Thus it can save much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that. However that will increase the size of your TFRecord file quite a bit. As a jpeg image is usually using 8bit you can pass it as a bytes_list feature. A good example on how to do that can be found [here](http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html)